# Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string while using the function

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, datetime

I have a function that returns a `datetime2`.

```
...
MS_VatToDate (@vYEAR smallint, @vMONTH smallint, @vDAY smallint)  

...

DECLARE @VatDate DATETIME2;
DECLARE @VatDateText VARCHAR(11);

SET @VatDateText = CAST(@vYEAR AS VARCHAR(4)) + '-' + 
                   CAST(@vMONTH AS VARCHAR(2)) + '-' +
                   CAST(@vDAY AS VARCHAR(2));

SET @VatDate = CONVERT(DATETIME2, @VatDateText, 126);
RETURN(@VatDate);
```

When I specify data it works just fine, but when I specify some range I get an error.

> Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

The same thing happened when I tried to apply this function for whole database, but at start I'm getting correct result and then at the end it's the same error.

Comment: Your code looks OK-ish except that it will fail if the numbers are invalid e.g. you specify 31 for April or 29 for Feb 2018. I am afraid most other functions (datefrompart, etc) will give you same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose you can use [`ISDATE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/isdate-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) function prior to conversion:

```
DECLARE @VatDate datetime2;
DECLARE @VatDateText varchar(11);
SET @VatDateText = CAST(@vYEAR as varchar(4)) + '-' + CAST(@vMONTH as varchar(2)) + '-' + CAST(@vDAY as varchar(2));

IF ISDATE(@VatDateText) = 1
    SET @VatDate = convert(datetime2, @VatDateText, 126);
ELSE
    PRINT @VatDateText + ' is invalid';

SELECT /* RETURN */ @VatDate;
```

Comment: It works in this form `SET @VatDateText = CAST(@vRok as varchar(4)) + '-' + CAST(@vMiesiac as varchar(2)) + '-' + CAST(@vDzien as varchar(2));
  IF ISDATE(@VatDateText) = 1
    SET @VatDate = convert(datetime2, @VatDateText, 126);
  ELSE
    SET @VatDate = ''

 return(@VatDate);` but i guess it's not perfect form, for production.

Comment: If you have invalid dates then you must fix them. There is no point searching for records on April 31st.

Answer (score 1):

Why are you writing your own function?

SQL Server offers [`datefromparts()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datefromparts-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017), so you an just write:

```
select datefromparts(2018, 11, 30)
```

If you want a `datetime2`:

```
select convert(datetime2, datefromparts(2018, 11, 30))
```

Or [`datetime2fromparts()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datetime2fromparts-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017):

```
select datetime2fromparts(2018, 11, 30, 0, 0, 0)
```

Support for SQL Server 2008 R2 ends in July, 2019, so you should update before support ends.

In the older system, you can convert without a format -- unless your default date format is YDM:

```
 set @VatDateText = cast(@vYEAR as varchar(4))+'-'+cast(@vMONTH as varchar(2))+'-'+cast(@vDAY as varchar(2));
 set @VatDate     = convert(datetime2, convert(date, @VatDateText));
```

Comment: You have to notice that `datefromparts()` will be working only for SQL Server 2012 and above. Maybe OP using older version of SQL Server?

Comment: 2008 still here :( 'datefromparts' is not a recognized built-in function name.

Answer (score 0):

If you can't use [DATEFROMPARTS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datefromparts-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) (it is available since SQL Server 2012), remove the dashes and cast the string directly. '20181130' will be successfully converted to date, regardless of your locale and dates settings. In this case it could also be that you have single digit month/day in your data and the constructed string is not valid, so add leading zeroes.

```
declare @VatDate datetime2;
declare @VatDateText varchar(11);

 set @VatDateText = cast(@vYEAR as varchar(4))+right('0' +cast(@vMONTH as varchar(2)), 2)+right('0' + cast(@vDAY as varchar(2)), 2);
 set @VatDate     = cast(@VatDateText as datetime2);
 return(@VatDate);
```

Comment: Did you removed the dashes? This code works. The other possible explanation is that you are trying to convert invalid data, e.g. Feb 29th on non-leap year, or something like that.